Migrating from spring integration 5.5 to 6.3
Given we no longer have IntegrationComponentSpec.get() and the correct solution is to use the ChannelSpec rather than the Channel. But how would I apply this with Kotlin DSL?
Before I could do:
    @Bean
    fun ftpMoveFileChannel(): PublishSubscribeChannel {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get()
    }


And then use that channel as the first argument to integrationFlow:
    @Bean
    fun moveFileFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return integrationFlow(ftpMoveFileChannel()) {
            handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "payload"))
            enrichHeaders {
                header("type", "download")
            }
            channel(transferredChannel())
        }
    }

But it seems that if I want to use a MessageSpec I have to use IntegrationFlow.from:
    @Bean
    fun ftpMoveFileChannel(): PublishSubscribeChannelSpec<*> {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe()
    }
    
    @Bean
    fun moveFileFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(ftpMoveFileChannel())
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "payload"))
            .enrichHeaders { spec ->
                spec.header("type", "download")
            }
            .channel(transferredChannel())
            .get()
    }

Is it possible to still use a more "Kotlin DSL way"? The above looks very much Java-ish.
EDIT: I saw on spring-integration-aws that in the example they just do:
    @Bean
    public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

Could I then just swap out return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get() to PublishSubscribeChannel()?

Yes, the PublishSubscribeChannel() is correct to use for you.
Another way is just use a channel namme in that DSL definition instead.
Also, it is recommended to use bean method arguments injection instead of calling other bean methods:
@Bean
fun moveFileFlow(ftpMoveFileChannel: PublishSubscribeChannel): IntegrationFlow {
    return integrationFlow(ftpMoveFileChannel) {

This way your ftpMoveFileChannel bean definition still could be a ChannelSpec. Since it is a FactoryBean, the injection is resolved correctly for the target object produced by this spec.

Why is it correct for me? What would the difference be if I used a ChannelSpec instead?

There is just no Kotlin integrationFlow(channel: ChannelSpec, flow: KotlinIntegrationFlowDefinition.() -> Unit) variant. So, have bean method as ChannelSpec and calling it from another bean definition is not going to work.

The MessageChannels is just a convenient builder API. You indeed still can go with Java (Kotlin) plain PublishSubscribeChannel() and use its setters instead. The only problem that ChannelSpec has more internal logic to satisfy builder pattern logic. Spring container still will work well, but only with a result of that ChannelSpec. Therefore a recommendation to use a method arguments injection instead of bean method calls. See also @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods) Javadocs.
